# Does a job scheduled in crontab run even when I log out?

Tags: cron

I add some job in crontab file on a server.

- When I log out and the server is still on, will the job still run?
- Does it matter if I create a screen or tmux session and run some shell in it and detach it before log out?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`cron` is a process which deals with scheduled tasks whether you are logged in or not. It is not necessary to have a screen or tmux session running since the cron daemon will execute the scheduled tasks in separate shells.

See `man cron` and `man crontab` for details.

Comment: when I log out, which user will run and own the job scheduled in crontab? If it is not me, can that cause some potential problem?

Comment: That depends on which crontab you edited. If you edit the crontab of a user the entries are executed as that user. If you edited the /etc/crontab file the user is often specified between the interval and the command like: "17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly". Besides it does also depend on the platform you are using. Ubuntu uses a different cron than for instance Solaris

Comment: I use ubuntu. What is "the crontab of a user"? In "the crontab of a user", can I also specify which user will run a scheduled job?

Comment: Ubuntu cron has some explanation text in the crontab files. As a user perform `crontab -e` to read about the user crontab file and `cat /etc/crontab` to read about the server-wide crontab file. From a user crontab file you can not run commands using a different user although it is possible to use sudo if passwordless commands are specified

Comment: Thanks. `/etc/crontab ` is for system-wide, then where is the crontab file for a user?

Comment: According to `man crontab` on Ubuntu the user crontab file is located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. But be carefull, the manual also say that those files are not intended for direct editing. You should use `crontab -e` from the user context or `crontab -e -u username` from the root user to edit the user crontab.

Comment: Thanks. I just got [a reply](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197510/674) which says we can make a user's crontab file to be `~/.crontab` by `crontab ~/.crontab`. Is it a good suggestion?

Comment: While reading the referenced reply the main purpose is that you have a (backup) copy of the crontab. If backups are arranged properly you should not have to do this by yourself.

Comment: it should be noted that user crontabs often require that the home folder of that user to be mounted to do useful work. this can be a problem if the users have encrypted home folders decrypted at login (e.g. with ecryptfs). encrypted homes are less common in server scenarios, granted.

Comment: macOS: I beg to differ

Comment: @Tim: I believe you misunderstood the reply: `~/.crontab` is not a special file and not  your _actual_ crontab. It's merely a local file you may keep for backup purposes, and you can name it whatever you want, say `~/crontab.txt`. You can _**save**_ it to your crontab using `crontab ~/crontab.txt` and generate it with `crontab -l > ~/crontab.txt`